# OAuth 2.0 Password Expiry when Obtaining an Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I am writing an API that uses the OAuth 2.0 [password flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) to authenticate users. When a request for an access token is denied, there does not seem to be any way for a client to tell whether the password was incorrect, or expired. From [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2), an error code of `invalid_grant` should be returned in both cases:

> invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.

Is it acceptable to use the `error_description` on the response to state that the password has expired so that the client can take the necessary action, and if not, what is the standard approach for handling password expiry with OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

"Leaking" that the reason for such a failure such as "password was incorrect, or expired" is NOT a best practice for authentication.

I would suggest that the "server" log the reason for the failure and NOT return the information to the requestor.

Comment: I agree that it could be a security concern to return the reason for a failed login. How then might a client application with a login form choose between showing an error message "Login failed" vs redirecting the user to the update password page?

Comment: IMHO, the client should not host any login page. The login page would be hosted by the IDP (Google or Facebook or ...) and they would know what redirect to perform. If you need authentication you should use OpenID Connect and NOT OAuth. https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/